# .Net HTMLAgilityPack is adding empty quotes to a tag attribute

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

I'm currently using the HMLAgilityPack to edit a html file.

My template has this piece of html:

```
<model-viewer class="viewer" id="viewer1" ar ar-modes="scene-viewer quick-look" ar-scale="auto" environment-image="neutral" src="mymodel.glb" camera-controls auto-rotate></model-viewer>
```

However, when I edit and save this document it adds an empty attribute to some parts of this tag. For example, the saved html looks like below, where ar, camera-controls, and auto-rotate have had empty quotes added.

```
<model-viewer class="viewer" id="viewer1" ar="" ar-modes="scene-viewer quick-look" ar-scale="auto" environment-image="neutral" src="mymodel.glb" camera-controls="" auto-rotate=""></model-viewer>
```

How do I stop

```
ar
```

in the modelviewer tag becoming

```
ar=""
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/issues/422

Set `htmlDoc.GlobalAttributeValueQuote = AttributeValueQuote.WithoutValue`

```
        var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
             <html>
             <body a b c>
             </body>
             </html> ";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
        htmlDoc.GlobalAttributeValueQuote = AttributeValueQuote.WithoutValue;
        htmlDoc.Save(@"./test.html");
        // <!DOCTYPE html>
          //   <html>
           //  <body a b c>
           //  </body>
           // </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful to see they are allowing for different scenarios. If I use initial I get ar='', and if I uses None I get ar= with no quotes at all. Is there an option that would remove the = too or would I pass that attribute value, then strip the equals myself another way? Thanks again

Comment: There is also AttributeValueQuote.WithoutValue but that unfortunately removes values for every attribute inside that tag which is no good to me either.